# How to change object button to integer

Tags: android, button, conditional-statements

I have 6 object button

```
kartu1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.kartu1);
kartu2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.kartu2);
kartu3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.kartu3);
kartu4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.kartu4);
kartu5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.kartu5);
kartu6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.kartu6);
```

All this object set to OnclickListener

```
       kartu1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        r = new Random();
        int i = r.nextInt(gamb.size());
        v.setBackgroundDrawable(gamb.get(i));
        }
    });
```

I want to make all the object as an integer, cause there is a condition to count all the object. I have a condition.

```
if (kartu1 >= 5){

}
```

How to change kartu1 to integer?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve..?

Comment: You asked the same question before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109324/how-to-convert-an-object-button-to-integer and it is still not clear what exactly you want. What integer do you want to get from the Button? The id? A pre-set number?

Comment: i'm developing a game, a matching image game, i set all the image as a button, if a button is clicked there will be background change, there is a limit to click the button, the limit is 5, if user clicked more than 5, then the button will be false(cannot be clicked), i have a problem to make all the button object to integer,  to make a condition above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
int[] ids={R.id.kartu1 ,R.id.kartu2, R.id.kartu3, R.id.kartu4, R.id.kartu5,R.id.kartu6  };
int clicks=0;
for(int i=0;i<ids.length;i++)
{
Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.kartu1);
b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        r = new Random();
        int i = r.nextInt(gamb.size());
        v.setBackgroundDrawable(gamb.get(i));
        // set the click count in variable
         clicks+=1;

         if(clicks>=5){
            // do stuff here
          }              
        }
    });
}
```

**Second Case.**

Above assumes that Total clicks on all images 5

if you want to set individual button click count of 5 do like this

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
            r = new Random();
            int i = r.nextInt(gamb.size());
            v.setBackgroundDrawable(gamb.get(i));
            // set the click count in variable
            String count=b.getContentDescription();
             if(count!=null && count.length()!=0)
             {
                 int cnt=Integer.parseInt(count);
                  cnt+=1;
             button.setContentDescription(String.valueOf(cnt));
              if(cnt>=5)
            {
               // do stuff here
            }
              }  
              else
              {
                button.setContentDescription(String.valueOf(1));
               }

            }
```